# Split words with Tesseract tess-two on Android

Tags: java, android, tesseract, tess-two

I try to use tesseract tess-two to read question and answears from images in android. At the moment I get a String with every word on the image.
My problem is that I can't split the answears
Is it possible to split the answear with TessBaseAPI? A solution in java/android would be also fine ;)

```
 public String detectText(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Initialization of TessBaseApi");
    TessDataManager.initTessTrainedData(context);
    TessBaseAPI tessBaseAPI = new TessBaseAPI();
    String path = TessDataManager.getTesseractFolder();
    Log.d(TAG, "Tess folder: " + path);
    tessBaseAPI.setDebug(true);
    tessBaseAPI.init(path, "eng");
    tessBaseAPI.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" +
            "abcdefghijklnmopqrstuvwxyzäüößÄÖÜ!?@#$%^&*+=-;()/");
    tessBaseAPI.setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED);

    Log.d(TAG, "Ended initialization of TessEngine");
    Log.d(TAG, "Running inspection on bitmap");
    tessBaseAPI.setImage(bitmap);

    String inspection = tessBaseAPI.getUTF8Text();
    Log.d(TAG, "Got data: " + inspection);
    tessBaseAPI.end();
    System.gc();
    return inspection;
}
```

[image: Here is an example how the image look like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way how it works:

```
tessBaseAPI.setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.PageSegMode.PSM_SPARSE_TEXT);
```